# Adding an array to a certain key in a Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP and am having some problems.

I have a Multidimensional array displays as such.

```
array (size=4)
  'debt Reduction' => 
     array (size=2)
      'credit card ' => string '495.00' (length=6)
      'Student Loan' => string '40.00' (length=5)
  'gifts' => 
     array (size=2)
      'Birthday' => string '23.00' (length=5)
      'Christmas' => string '49.00' (length=5)
  'personal' => 
     array (size=2)
      'Gym Memberships' => string '138.00' (length=6)
      'Hair Cuts' => string '40.00' (length=5)
  'saving' => 
     array (size=2)
      'Emergency Fund' => string '80.00' (length=5)
      'wedding' => string '60.00' (length=5)
```

Which is made by using this

```
$sortedArray = array();
foreach ($SQLresults as $row)
{
    $sortedArray[$row['catagoryName']][$row['Subcatagory_name']] = $row['expenseAmount'];
}
```

This array then goes into a function to produce a series of HTML results

I have another array which displays the total amount of each section, this outputs as

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
     array (size=1)
       'expenseAmount' => string '535.00' (length=6)
  1 => 
     array (size=1)
       'expenseAmount' => string '72.00' (length=5)
  2 => 
     array (size=1)
       'expenseAmount' => string '178.00' (length=6)
  3 => 
     array (size=1)
       'expenseAmount' => string '140.00' (length=6)
```

I thought I could just take out the `expenseAmount` text and enter it into a function I made

```
foreach ($expenseAmount as $rowe => $new)
{
    $type[] = $new['expenseAmount'];
}
```

This takes out the expenseAmount text

Below is the function I am using to output html (`$array` represents the new array)

```
public function dropdownTally($groupedCatagories, $number_of_rows, $array)
{    
    $output = '';
    if($number_of_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach ($groupedCatagories as $category => $subCategories)
        {
            $output .= '<input type="button"id="showdiv"class="btn btn-link dropdownCats"value="'.$category.''.$array.'">';

            $output .= '<div id="div" class ="newClassTest" style="display:none">';
            $output .= '<table class="dynamicExpenseTable">';
            $output .= '<tr class="tableRows">';

            foreach ($subCategories as $title => $amount)
            {
                $output .='<td class="dataExpense">'.$title.'</td>';
                $output .='<td class="dataExpense">'. $amount.'</td>'; 
                $output .='</tr>';
            }
            $output .='</table>  ';
            $output .='</div>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= '<p>No data found</p>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

As you can see I am trying to add on the total value of each category to go next to the name of it.

The output is either one of two things :

-Either 'array to string conversion'.

After some playing around, I thought I would wrap it in another `foreach` statement and just repeats the button and output over and over.

So my question is, should I try and push the second array into the first, how would this be done to output something like ?

```
array (size=4)
  'debt Reduction' => 
       '535.00'
     array (size=2)
      'credit card ' => string '495.00' (length=6)
      'Student Loan' => string '40.00' (length=5)
  'gifts' => 
       '72.00'
      array (size=2)
      'Birthday' => string '23.00' (length=5)
      'Christmas' => string '49.00' (length=5)
```

Or is there an easier way to achieve what I am saying ? Sorry for the verbose post I just wanted to try and get across my problem.

Thanks again
Jack

Comment: `value="'.$category.''.$array.'"` in `dropdownTally`. What are you expecting this to do? (this is certainly the array to string conversion error)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. That is what I said in the description, and what I was expecting, but then I tried to wrap the input in another foreach so it wouldnt be anymore which results in repeating values. The question is more aimed towards pushing one array into a certain key of a multidimensional one. :)

Comment: `<input type="button" value="something">` will write something on the button. My question was really what do you expect to be written on that button ?

Comment: Ahh sorry It would be something like <input type="button" value="debt Reduction 
 : 535.00">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many little mistakes when you're generating the `$output` variable.

Add some spaces between attribute value and next attribute name. You wrote `type="button"id="showdiv"class="btn btn-link dropdownCats"value="..."` this can lead to some error about reading the code.

```
$output .= '<input type="button" id="showdiv" class="btn btn-link dropdownCats" value="'.$category.''.$array.'">';
```

Then, `id="showdiv"` in a loop is wrong. ids have to be unique. You might want to use classes or specify a value for that div.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($groupedCatagories as $category => $subCategories)
{
    $i++;
    $output .= '<input type="button" id="showdiv_' . $i . '" ...>';
    //left of code
}
```

Next, as you stated in comments, the value of the button is expected to be `"debt Reduction : 535.00"` and you wrote `value="' . $category . $array. '"`

I suppose that thoses values come from the first array you shown

```
'debt Reduction' => 
    array (size=2)
        'credit card ' => string '495.00' (length=6)
        'Student Loan' => string '40.00' (length=5)
```

The 535 being the addition of both `'credit card '` and `Student Loan`.

That value might need to be computed before trying to display it.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($groupedCatagories as $category => $subCategories)
{
    $i++;
    $buttonValue = 0;
    foreach ($subCategories as $value)
        $buttonValue += floatval($value);
    $buttonValue = $category . ' : ' . $buttonValue;

    $output .= '<input type="button" id="showdiv_' . $i . '" class="btn btn-link dropdownCats" value="' . $buttonValue . '">';
    //...
}
```

Like previously, you define an hardcoded id in a loop `$output .= '<div id="div_' . $i . '" class ="newClassTest" style="display:none">';`.

Finally, the generated HTML is invalid. You open a `<tr>` tag outside of a loop, then close it inside that loop. That will result this kind of HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>     <!-- notice the closed <tr> not being re-opened -->
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You might want to open and close it inside the loop.

```
foreach ($subCategories as $title => $amount)
{
    $output .= '<tr class="tableRows">';
    $output .= '<td class="dataExpense">' . $title . '</td>';
    $output .= '<td class="dataExpense">' .  $amount . '</td>'; 
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
```

Final code could be like this :

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($groupedCatagories as $category => $subCategories)
{
    $i++;
    $buttonValue = 0;
    foreach ($subCategories as $value)
        $buttonValue += floatval($value);
    $buttonValue = $category . ' : ' . $buttonValue;

    $output .= '<input type="button" id="showdiv_' . $i . '" class="btn btn-link dropdownCats" value="' . $buttonValue . '">';


    $output .= '<div id="div_' . $i . '" class ="newClassTest" style="display:none">';
    $output .= '<table class="dynamicExpenseTable">';

    foreach ($subCategories as $title => $amount)
    {
        $output .= '<tr class="tableRows">';
        $output .= '<td class="dataExpense">' . $title . '</td>';
        $output .= '<td class="dataExpense">' .  $amount . '</td>'; 
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>  ';
    $output .= '</div>';
}
```